# Raspberry Pi as Remote Outdoor Time lapse Camera. Can Hot weather bricks raspi?

Tags: camera, remote, web

I would like to know if anyone here has used raspberry pi as a remote timelapse camera.
my concern is Heat, because it will be installed at fabrication site near Malacca Straits shore (35°C or 95°F )
will it be okay running 24/7 for a year?

some steps I already prepared  are:

1. CCTV outdoor housing
2. Heat sinks and Fan
3. Solar panel as extra shade

kindly share anything for me to take note as tips, tricks and precaution so that I'll save maintenance trips cost

Answer (score 1):

Sydney regularly tops 40C in summer, and Pi works without problems.

Whether you need heatsinks/fan depends on model and application.
It would obviously be prudent NOT to leave the Pi in direct sunlight.

Personally I would be more concerned about humidity.